# « Y télécharger », « y installer » : pourquoi « y » est utilisé ?

Tags: pronoms, indications-de-lieu

Je lisais un petit texte sur le lancement d'une console de jeu vidéo quand j'ai vu la phrase suivante:

> L’appareil dispose d’une fente pour lire les jeux mobiles PS Vita, mais il est aussi possible d’**y** télécharger certains jeux plus anciens localement, comme des jeux PSN et PlayStation One. À noter que la capacité interne limitée forcera toutefois l’utilisateur à s’équiper d’une carte média s’il veut **y** installer quelques jeux à la fois.

Le pronom *y* a été utilisé deux fois :

> mais il est aussi possible d’**y** télécharger

et

> toutefois l’utilisateur à s’équiper d’une carte média s’il veut **y** installer quelques jeux à la fois

Je sais que l'on utilise *y* pour remplacer quelque chose après « à », par exemple :

> Tu joues au football (ou soccer) ? Oui, bien sûr, j'y joue.

Dans ce cas, *y* remplace « au football ».

Dans le petit texte que j'ai mis au-dessus, les verbes « télécharger » et « vouloir » ne demandent pas « à ». Donc pourquoi le pronom *y* a été mis en place ?

Quelle est la règle que je ne connais pas ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dans ces deux cas, le pronom **y** remplace un **complément de lieu** :

> Mais il est aussi possible de télécharger des jeux *(où ?) sur la console*.

devient ici :

> Mais il est aussi possible d’*y* télécharger des jeux.

De même :

> […] forcera toutefois l’utilisateur à s’équiper d’une carte média s’il veut installer quelques jeux à la fois *dans la mémoire de la console*.

est remplacé ici par :

> […] forcera toutefois l’utilisateur à s’équiper d’une carte média s’il veut *y* installer quelques jeux à la fois.

Comment: Wow, c'est simple! Je ne savais pas que l'on pouvait utiliser le y pour remplacer un place si le place etait precedé par une preposition comme dans ou sur! C'est très simple pour comprendre, je suis embarrassé :) Merci beaucoup!